# SQL Server 2012 connection with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have some code to work on, I tried to change the connection but it won't work.

The previous connection:

```
<%
    set Conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source = (local); Initial Catalog = paytimepayrollhris; User Id = sa; Password= testl"
%>
```

I changed it to......

```
<%
    set Conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source = MSZ900; Initial Catalog = paytimepayrollhris; integrated security=true;"
%>
```

Error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can your user login to this server using windows logon?

Comment: you would need to add this as well : 
persist security info=True;user id=xyz;password=xyzpassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;

Comment: your code doesn't look like c#, it looks like asp3 with vbscript. are you sure that this is the correct code? Also, make sure you can connect to `MSZ900` using ssms from the machine that code runs on.